# How can I display the parts of custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called Testimonial that includes custom fields "name", "title" and "bank". I would like to display each of these items on a page. Here's what I have so far:

```
    <?php
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      the_title();
      echo '<div class="entry-content">';
      the_content();
      echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

This gives me something close to what I want but I don't know how to get at the actual fields individually. How do I do that?

Comment: How do you mean to get the fields individually? Are you looking for functions like [`the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) and [`the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div class="custom-field">';
  echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'name', true );
  echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'title', true );
  echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'bank', true );
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

This is how you would display the custom fields below the content. I didn't test it but it should work. Hope this helps. Also read Milo's answer and read the Codex so you understand how it works.

Also it looks like you are using a custom query object (`$loop`), so read this article as well:

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_Example_1

Answer (score 2):

See the [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) page in Codex for the various functions available to output your fields: [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom), [`get_post_custom_values`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values), [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), [`the_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_meta).